# Unknown Knight move

Tags: online-chess

I'm playing as white against a cpu. Black has a knight on A7, which he moved to D4 to capture my queen. How is this possible? I've been playing chess for almost 20 years and I have never seen ir heard of this move. Is this a special knight move? What is it called?

Comment: Na7xd4 is not a legal move. What chess engine? Do you have the PGN?

Comment: It's called a double jump. Oops, wrong game...

Comment: Indeed, that is not a legal move. Are you sure it wasn't a bishop instead of a knight, going from a7 to d4?

Comment: From A7, the only possibilities for knight are jumping to C file (C8, C6) or to B5. The rest are not possible. Seems like a computer bug!! What software are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Without further context, I can simply say that the move you described is not a legal knight move in any position or circumstance. It is, however, a legal move for a bishop. Perhaps you mistook the bishop for a knight.

If you could supply the PGN of the game, it would clear up some confusion.